# Calling .Net function from IronPython [VS2012]

Tags: .net, arrays, ironpython

I'm trying to call a .Net function from IronPython(VS-2012)

**.NET Function:**

```
public int GetData(uint numberOfSamples, float[] iBuffer, float[] qBuffer){..}
```

**IronPython:**

```
# Here's my code in IronPython
numSamples = 1024
from array import array
iData = array('f')
qData = array('f')

GetData(numSamples, iData, qData)
```

The Last line will throw the following exception, (from Locals Window -VS2012)

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: float in IronPython is equivalent to double in C# - Maybe this is the issue. Ref: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/calling%20infer.net%20from%20ironpython.aspx

Comment: I've also tried with `array('d')`, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array of `floats` (which are `System.Single`) like this:

```
iData = System.Array[System.Single]([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
qData = System.Array[System.Single]([4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
GetData(numSamples, iData, qData)
```

EDIT: In case you would like to preallocate array and have no actual python content, use:

```
iData = System.Array.CreateInstance(System.Single, 1024)
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel, This one seems to work but I want to define the size of an array not the values, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Though I accepted Pawals answer, I ended up using like this

```
iData = Array.CreateInstance(System.Single, 1024)
qData = Array.CreateInstance(System.Single, 1024)
```

I found from this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2008/03/12/8177915.aspx).

Comment: I guess we were researching at the same time :-)